Moving to Finland as self employed as a Day Trader in stocks
as non-EU citizen , Can I Move to Finland as self employed as a Day Trader in stocks?, I mean I generete income online. I'v heard about "toiminimi" or something similar. So? Thank you for any feedback.

To be an entrepreneur or to enter a self-employed profession in Finland, you must obtain a residence permit for the purpose of entrepreneurship.
You are an entrepreneur if you are

a private entrepreneur who has a so called individually-owned business (toiminimi)

Information about documents you may need to provide and the application/decision process to obtain a residence permit for the purpose of entrepreneurship is available here
